# Partition struct collection into member collection

Tags: rust, vector, struct, collections, iterator

I want to convert a collection of struct type to collection of struct's member type.

```
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: i64,
    c: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Vec<Foo>;
    let (a, b, c): (Vec<&String>, Vec<&i64>, Vec<&f64>) = foo.iter(); // Not sure how.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Iterator::unzip()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.unzip):

```rust
let foo: Vec<Foo>;
let ((a, b), c): ((Vec<&str>, Vec<i64>), Vec<f64>) =
    foo.iter().map(|v| ((v.a.as_str(), v.b), v.c)).unzip();
```